# Flume: How to track specified sub folders using spoolDir?

Tags: flume, flume-ng

We're having a system uploads log files into a folder which named by date. It looks like:

```
/logs
   /20181030
   /20181031
   /20181101
   /20181102
   /...
```

Suppose that I want to track the log files which produced during November by using spoolDir, How could I do this ?

```
#this won't work
a1.sources.r1.spoolDir = /logs/201811??

#this seems only works with files. Is it possible to filter folders here?
a1.sources.r1.includePattern = ^.*\.txt$
```

Answer (score 0):

Acoording to the flume source code, folders that match the **ignorePattern** are skipped while recursing the folder tree(to register folder trackers). So you can ignore the folders which don't match your criteria. `^(?!201811..).*$` would exclude all the folders that are not folders of November 2018. Other folders will not be tracked.
But this pattern will also apply to file names. So any file with name that does not match `^201811..$` will also be ignored. You can add the `^.*\.txt$` pattern (the one you are using for the include pattern) to the regex to make flume accept your input files.

```
a1.sources.r1.ignorePattern = ^(?!(201810..)|(.*\\.txt)).*$
```

would do the trick for you.